# identityserver4 doesn't generate x5c, or x5t. x5c is null

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

My Identityserver4 `/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks` returns this:

```json
"keys": [{
    "kty": "RSA",
    "use": "sig",
    "kid": "658afeec71f865172646636c1964c00a",
    "e": "AQAB",
    "n": "utmbhyq_j1nhoNOGvj3TmEYb6pSYHo8PpzGr2VkNxdBx3GnKwv29rm0jwHw4l_o_HAAlws_okgdqjqyxUx9HH3fZkPlbNTGzufu7JSy_7kFS1KVsfIWj8CLaVPNJNE_2T6L7gWru86ASf0uCxc7Wsxqy6AWu9bIrAg4-Bz3Tlyclu6pqvNhetkIrc9IC_YKWjL3Udsk3UkEYcN8opOn5DLgw6ogBb7EOp-DEbcmY9YQCPBHCBTpqkkhRDI4HmT831Qn7UGB6L6K47CLBuUGjbI_QzW-lEQ0QeJE9zqJ5AThX1CbKhQgyX2sEEHPbrG_iZosltqRd7G6FF8jcaySwzQ",
    "alg": "RS256"
}]
```

The x5c and x5t are missing. Any idea why?

Comment: What problem is this causing? There's a demo version of IS4 hosted by the IS4 guys themselves that also [doesn't include these properties](https://demo.identityserver.io/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks).

Comment: @KirkLarkin I am implementing the solution that they have to protect a WCF server, look aht [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/WcfService/IdentityServerWrappedJwtHandler.cs)
On my own server, the idsr4 works fine, when I move it to the one on GoDaddy it doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find out any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually was on the web.config. I Had some extra lines bc I was testing things, and I removed them.
These are the lines that I removed them:

```xml
<environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

It was taking the developer Certificate.

Comment: Hm... I wonder why it doesn't return the x5c field when in developer mode. It still uses a certificate, so shouldn't it return it?